# How to pass state between function components using React Router Redirect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can variables be properly passed between function components? When the example variable in `Component1` is set, `Component1` redirects successfully to `Component2`. This example is using the [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/) `Redirect` component.

The code below results in the following error in `Component2`:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined`

Why is the location variable being passed into the signature of `Component2` undefined? How can the value be properly passed through the components using this Redirect?

**Component1.js**

```
...
if (example) 
{
    return (
        <Redirect
            to={{
                pathname: '/component2',
                state: { example: example},
            }}
        />
    );
}
...
```

**Component2.js**

```
export default function Component2({ location }) {
    const [example] = useState(location.state.example);
    return (
        <h1>Component2</h1>
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you instead try using the hook `useLocation` `let location = useLocation(); console.log(location.state);` instead? The documentation on [auth workflow](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow) shows redirect with state and how the component redirect to can use state.

Comment: `useLocation()` worked.

Comment: Whilst `useLocation()` works, that's not how you would conventionally share values between components. If it's just this once fair enough. But considering using [Lifting up state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)